# Removing Empty elements in a list and converting the remaining into floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

So, basically I have this list I got from the split() method:

```
mylist=['', '3', '', '', '7.00', '', '', '', '21.00']
```

and I want to remove the ' ' elements from my list and convert the remaining Strings into floats. Mind that the position or the number of ' ' elements may vary from String to String that I'm reading.

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
mylist=['', '3', '', '', '7.00', '', '', '', '21.00']
clean_list = [float(i) for i in mylist if i !='']

print(clean_list)
[3.0, 7.0, 21.0]
```

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float:  I got this error

Comment: Your code as is runs perfectly but i got this string from the split() method i do not know if that plays any part cuz im new to python.

Comment: post exactly the list that you got. Using split() should not be a problem. My answer works for any list that has strings as you posted in your question

Comment: better you put the code/example as easy to reproduce the issue you facing. Then it easy anyone to help you.

Comment: ok i got it fixed apparently i had one wrong line of code previous to yours and didnt work. Now it works perfectly thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [float(x) for x in mylist if x]
```

Comment: Hi py_dude, I think it's a good answer, empty sequences and collections are by default false. Maybe you want to explain this in a bit more detail?

Comment: @StupidWolf you have just explained everything. What else can I do for you?

Comment: Lol. Just hoping you add more, and lessen the chance of getting deleted.